# Uninstalling Windows 7 from dual boot of Win7/Xp

Tags: windows-7

How do I uninstall Windows 7 from my dual boot of Windows 7 and XP?  I've uninstalled Linux before but unlike Linux refixing the mbr does not work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to change the bootorder, simply erase Windows 7 from the list and then you can delete the Windows 7 partition.

[image]

That way you won't have to fix the MBR, since you already changed it. And it let's you back it up, so you don't have to worry too much.

[image]

Comment: Though I would like to add : the Write MBR Option seen in the second photo is all thats needed.

Comment: How do you mean? After you erase the Windows 7 partition you use Write MBR in XP?

Answer (score 1):

format the partition containing windows 7

Comment: won't that delete the bootloader?

Comment: After formatting you probaly have to boot with an XP CD and run fixmbr on the repair console.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.techspot.com/guides/144-removing-windows7/page2.html.

Deals with this exact issue. Essentially delete Windows 7 partition and use XP cd to repair the bootloader.

Comment: Thanks everybody , but my cd-drive just isn't dependable anymore. I had installed Win7 , Linux previously without using a cd. and to fix the mbr I had used the program MBRFIX(http://www.sysint.no/en/Download.aspx) instead.  Trying Easybcd mentioned above.